Expectation value of product of iid variables
Let $p(x)$ be a probability distribution with moments $\mu_n = \mathbb{E}[x^n] = \sum_x p(x) x^n$ and cumulants $C_k$. Let $X_1, \ldots, X_N$ be i.i.d. random variables selected from this distribution. Of course $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = \mu_1 = C_1$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_i X_j] = \mu_1^2(1-\delta_{ij})+\mu_2 \delta_{ij} = C_1^2 +\delta_{ij} C_2$. Also
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X_i X_j X_k] ={}& \mu_1^3 (1-\delta_{ij})(1-\delta_{jk})(1-\delta_{ki})+\mu_1\mu_2[\delta_{ij}(1-\delta_{jk})+\delta_{jk}(1-\delta_{ki})+\delta_{ki}(1-\delta_{ij})]+\mu_3\delta_{ij}\delta_{jk}\\
={}& C_1^3+C_1 C_2(\delta_{ij}+\delta_{jk}+\delta_{ki})+C_3\delta_{ij}\delta_{jk}
\end{align}
Clearly this pattern will continue; since the moments are all polynomials in the cumulants, it is always possible to express $\mathbb{E}[X_{i_1}\cdots X_{i_n}]$ as a sum of products of cumulants. Is there a straightforward way to write down the coefficients of each term in this expectation value?
